# How to handle onPress function react

Tags: javascript, debugging, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native with NativeBase components, and I am having a problem calling my _doStuff function. I tried to call

```
onPress={this._doStuff.bind(this)}
```

but keep receiving

> Cannot read properly 'doStuff' of undefined

```
_doStuff(){
 console.log('Hi');
   }

 _getList() {
 return this.state.listData.map(function(data, i){
return(

  <View key={i}>
  <ListItem style={styles.listItemContain}>
  <Button transparent onPress={this._doStuff.bind(this)}>

    <View>
    <Thumbnail source={{uri: data.icon}}  style={styles.thumbnailStyle}/>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{data.name}</Text>
    <Text note style={styles.text}>{data.vicinity}</Text>
    </View>
      </Button>

  </ListItem>
  </View>

);
 });
```

Comment: Are you using `React.createClass` or ES6 classes for your component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` context is lost inside the .map loop. if you are using ES6, try to use **fat arrow functions** as shown below.

```js
_getList() {
 return this.state.listData.map((data, i) => {
return(

  <View key={i}>
  <ListItem style={styles.listItemContain}>
  <Button transparent onPress={this._doStuff.bind(this)}>

    <View>
    <Thumbnail source={{uri: data.icon}}  style={styles.thumbnailStyle}/>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{data.name}</Text>
    <Text note style={styles.text}>{data.vicinity}</Text>
    </View>
      </Button>

  </ListItem>
  </View>

);
 });
```

if you cant use ES6 on your project due to various reasons use alternative approach(old school) as shown below...

```js
_getList() {
 return this.state.listData.map(function(data, i){
var that = this;
return(

  <View key={i}>
  <ListItem style={styles.listItemContain}>
  <Button transparent onPress={that._doStuff.bind(that)}>

    <View>
    <Thumbnail source={{uri: data.icon}}  style={styles.thumbnailStyle}/>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{data.name}</Text>
    <Text note style={styles.text}>{data.vicinity}</Text>
    </View>
      </Button>

  </ListItem>
  </View>

);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a wager that the context of your `_getList` function does not have the context of the React Component that you are thinking. If you are using ES6 classes and would like to get autobinding of the components context I would suggest using [autobind-decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator). If you decide to go that route here is [a nice tutorial on setting it up](http://technologyadvice.github.io/es7-decorators-babel6/).

Otherwise make sure that when you call `_getList` make sure to call it with either `.call` or `.bind`.

For example:

`// if you are calling the function directly
this._getList().call(this)`

or

`// if you are passing the function off for another function to execute it 
this._getList.bind(this)`